# AWS: Uploading Files via Lambda to S3 Bucket not working ( Reading is )

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using the aws cdk to create necessary ressources so for this i created

- a s3 container to hold the files
- one lambda to post files to s3 bucket
- one lambda to get files from s3 bucket

The S3 Container is created with following settings:

```
 const imageBucketProps: BucketProps = {
     bucketName: awsReferences.S3_SCREENSHOT_CONTAINER_BUCKET_NAME,
     publicReadAccess: true,
  };
 const imageBucket = new Bucket(this, id, imageBucketProps);

 imageBucket.grantReadWrite(getImageFunction);
 imageBucket.grantReadWrite(postImageFunction);
```

As i understand, now both lambdafunctions ( getImageFunction and postImageFunction ) are granted to access this bucket with full permissions ( i am changing to correct permissions when working as expected )

I uploaded manually a file into the bucket named mr_base.jpg and i can get the FileBuffer from the Bucket with this getImageFunction:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const awsReferences = require('./lib/config/aws_references.json');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
   let imageKey = 'mr_base.jpg';

   // prepare parameters for Bucket Get Request
   const params = {
      Bucket: awsReferences.S3_SCREENSHOT_CONTAINER_BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: imageKey,
   };

   s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
         callback(err, null);
      } else {
         let response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: {},
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            isBase64Encoded: false,
         };
         callback(null, response);
      }
   });
};
```

So i verified:

- Lambda Execution is successful without errors
- S3 Container existing
- Read Access granted to lambda function to the S3 Container

Now i want to upload files (images) to that folder and i am simplifying this with a textfile here to not copy paste a buffer in this.

the postImageFunction is also quite simple:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const awsReferences = require('./lib/config/aws_references.json');

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
   console.log('S3 Get Function has been called');

   let filename = 'file_' + Date.now() + '_' + 'user_id' + '.txt';
   let content = 'hi i am your content';

   var filePath = filename;

   const params = {
      Body: content,
      Bucket: awsReferences.S3_SCREENSHOT_CONTAINER_BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: filePath,
   };

   console.log('s3 Upload s3 params', params);

   s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
      console.log('s3 upload function called at', Date.now());
      if (err) {
         console.log('error', err);
         callback(err, null);
      } else {
         console.log('data', data);

         let response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: {
               my_header: 'my_value',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            isBase64Encoded: false,
         };
         callback(null, response);
      }
   });
};
```

Unfortunatly i can not see any error in Cloudwatch nor can i get any of the logs that are inside

```
s3.upload(params, function(err, data) { … }
```

What i verified here:

- s3 is an Object and having AWS related informations in there
- params is also an object with expected keys and values

I experienced a lot of times that access rights might be an issue, but Cloudwatch was always offering logs regarding any issues here. Unfortunately i have no idea what is happening here.

Did i miss something? This looks pretty straightforward and also tutorials like:

https://medium.com/think-serverless/image-upload-and-retrieval-from-s3-using-aws-api-gateway-and-lambda-b4c2961e8d1

seem to refer to same code.

I am thankful for any hint, even if it is manual settings at first, i can figure out, how to do equivalent in cdk, i guess. :)

Cloudwatch Log for one Invocation:

```js
START RequestId: dcf92d06-0f27-4495-a1e3-87419fc43a70 Version: $LATEST
2019-12-06T09:23:29.896Z dcf92d06-0f27-4495-a1e3-87419fc43a70 INFO S3 Get Function has been called
2019-12-06T09:23:29.899Z dcf92d06-0f27-4495-a1e3-87419fc43a70 INFO s3 Upload s3 params { Body: 'hi i am your content',
  Bucket: 'screen-shot-container-bucket',
  Key: 'file_1575624209897_user_id.txt' }
END RequestId: dcf92d06-0f27-4495-a1e3-87419fc43a70
REPORT RequestId: dcf92d06-0f27-4495-a1e3-87419fc43a70 Duration: 59.62 ms Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 95 MB Init Duration: 379.97 ms
```

Update:

I created an IAM User ( AmazonS3FullAccess ) and updated config with credentials of this user. But same result.

```js
const { ACCESS_KEY_ID, SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_REGION } = process.env;
AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: ACCESS_KEY_ID, secretAccessKey: SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, region: AWS_REGION });
```

Comment: Code seems reasonable. Can you include the entire CloudWatch log for an invocation (obfuscating any sensitive parts)? From the START log through END and the final REPORT.

Comment: If this function has deployed successfully as a lambda, it should have produced logs.

Comment: Also check to see if your Lambda's assigned IAM role has permission to write logs to Cloudwatch

Comment: i added the full log, which is small, but as we can see, the lambda's function 'console.log' outputs are included. it seems like that the action s3.upload(…) is not executed?

Comment: Do you have a timeout configured. Looks like the lambda didn't finish execution

Comment: yes i did set it to 16 seconds but how do you see that the lambda did not finish? Can you see this in the logs? i thought when there is an "END" in logs, i can assume the lambda has been executed fully?

Comment: Because your logs does not contain `s3 upload function called at`. So it's not executed right

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you check the logs

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-logs.html

Comment: thank you, but cloudwatch is one of my core tools for developing. i am just wondering why i can not see (mis)-behaviour in cloudwatch :)

Comment: How did u create the lambda, are you  using serverless framework

Comment: i am using cdk to deploy the lambdas. so we are serverless and stateless here.

Answer (score 0):

ok thanks guys, i found a working solution. basically we can await the s3.upload method and then it reduces to following code. ( No extra IAM User needed since Permissions are granted )

This makes sense to me, since uploading will take some time

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const awsReferences = require('./lib/config/aws_references.json');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
   console.log('S3 Get Function has been called');

   let filename = 'file_' + Date.now() + '_' + 'user_id' + '.txt';
   let content = 'hi i am your content';

   var filePath = filename;

   const params = {
      Body: content,
      Bucket: awsReferences.S3_SCREENSHOT_CONTAINER_BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: filePath,
   };

   try {
      const { Location, Key } = await s3.upload(params).promise();
      location = Location;
      key = Key;
   } catch (error) {}

   console.log(location, key);
};
```